# Erros Acentuação QueryPath

Tags: php, parser

Estou usando uma das libraries recomendadas [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/).
Para obter os dados estou usando [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Porém, estou com problemas no retorno de dados (acentuação), ele está substituindo os caracteres por `?`.

**OBS:** O problema não é no `Guzzle`, pois testei com outro parser, que segundo a resposta acima não é um dos recomendados... e também não continuei sua utilização por não atender alguns html's complexos que preciso tratar... mas o fato é, que ele retornou a acentuação corretamente.

**Soluções testadas sem sucesso:**

```
//Primeira Tentativa
$content = mb_convert_encoding($resposta->getBody()->getContents(), 'UTF-8', 'auto');
$html = htmlqp($content); // Problema acentuação ?????????

//Segunda Tentativa
$html5 = new HTML5();
$content = $html5->loadHTML($resposta->getBody()->getContents());
$html = htmlqp($content); // Problema acentuação ?????????

//Terceira Tentativa
$qp = html5qp($resposta->getBody()->getContents());

//Quarta Tentativa
$options = ['convert_to_encoding' => 'UTF-8'];
$qp = htmlqp($resposta->getBody()->getContents(), null, $options);
```

Já não sei mais o que testar.... O que poderia ser?